# MongoDB data modeling: how to compare a sub-document field with a root document field?

Tags: mongodb

In a MongoDB collection, I am trying to model some hardware "devices" which have some "inputs", with the following constraint: a **single input should be active at a time**.

Here is the (simplified) document I am using to model a device with its inputs:

```json
{
    "_id" : "device1",
    "inputs" : [ 
        {
            "connectedTo" : "device3",
            "index" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "connectedTo" : null,
            "index" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "connectedTo" : null,
            "index" : 4
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I am trying to implement the "active" input feature. I see two way of doing that:

1. add an "activeInput" field in the root document storing the index of the active input
2. add a "active" flag (boolean) field on each input sub-document, with only a single input with active flag set to true

However, I have some problems writing MongoDB updates with both approaches:

With approach 1: I can't find a way to query/update the active input sub-document. Here is what I tried as filters:

```js
{"inputs.index": {"$eq": "$activeInput"}}
```

```js
{"$where": "this.inputs.index==this.activeInput"}
```

```js
{"$expr": {"$eq": ["$inputs.index", "$activeInput"]}}
```

It seems that we can't compare fields of sub-document, or I can't find how to do that.

With approach 2: I can't find a way to update the active flag atomically so that only one input is active at a time. I need to set the active flag to true for the sub-document with the given index value, and to false for the other sub-documents, but I have no idea how to do that atomatically.

Maybe I've not found the right way to model the "active" input feature, so can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With approach 1**

You may solve this with an update pipeline, but it will be quite complicated:

- Compute a new field `newActiveInput` containing the future new active input
- Update `activeInput` and `inputs` fields
- Remove the `newActiveInput` field

```js
db.getCollection('test').update(
    {"_id" : "device1"},
    [
        {
            "$addFields": {
                "newActiveInput": {
                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                        {
                            "$map": {
                                "input": {
                                    "$filter": {
                                        "input": "$inputs",
                                        "cond": {
                                            "$and": [
                                                {"$ne": ["$$this.index", "$activeInput"]},
                                                {"$eq": ["$$this.connectedTo", null]}
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "as": "input",
                                "in": "$$input.index"
                            },
                        }, 0
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$set": {
                "activeInput": "$newActiveInput",
                "inputs": {     
                   "$concatArrays": [
                       {
                           "$filter": {
                               "input": "$inputs",
                               "cond": {"$lt": ["$$this.index", "$newActiveInput"]}
                           }
                       },
                       [{"connectedTo": "newDevice", "index": "$newActiveInput"}],
                       {
                           "$filter": {
                               "input": "$inputs",
                               "cond": {"$gt": ["$$this.index", "$newActiveInput"]}
                           }
                       },
                   ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
           "$unset": "newActiveInput"
        }
    ]
)
```

**With approach 2**

The following update will to set `active=true` if `connectedTo == "device4"` and `active=false` otherwise:

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
  {"_id" : "device1"},
  [
    {
      "$set": {
        "inputs": {     
           "$map": {
             "input": "$inputs",
             "as": "input",
             "in": {
               "$mergeObjects": [
                 "$$input",
                 {
                   "active": { "$cond": [ {"$eq": ["$$input.connectedTo", "device4"]}, true, false ] }
                 }
               ]
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
)
```

Another solution is to use `arrayFilters` to identify subdocuments to be updated, and then `$bit` update to invert current `active` value. Since `$bit` only works with integers, you will need to represent `active` as an integer:

```
db.getCollection('test').update(
    {
        "_id" : "device1"
    },
    {
        "$bit": {"inputs.$[input].active" : {"xor": NumberInt(1)}}
    },
    {
        "multi": true,
        "arrayFilters": [
            {
                "$or": [
                    {"input.active": NumberInt(1)},
                    {"input.connectedTo": "device5"},
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
)
```